# Solve: $\int_a^b\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{x}+\sin(x)\right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral $$\int_a^b\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{x}+\sin(x)\right)dx.$$

I have tried some basic substitution and integration by parts, but beyond that can seem to solve find an analytical solution. I was able to solve it numerically for which an example solution is shown in the picture with the integral on the $y$ axis and $x$ on the $x$ axis. It looks like a Bessel or sinusoidal exponential to me.

[image]

Comment: If I am not wrong the integral diverges because, the term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}$ diverges  when $x=a$

Comment: And I also found something helpful to solve this integral. When we split the integral into two integrals. We get $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{cos(x)}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}$ and $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{sin(x)}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}$                Now if I let $I(t)=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{cos(xt)}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}$ then $I'(t)$ is exactly the negative of second integral evaluated at 1. So it's enough just to evaluate the first integral.

Comment: Bad news: Wolfram Alpha is stuck, even on separate terms.

Comment: @Bobby Laspy, have a look at my answer, I solved the answer to some extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to my comment I found an answer. I will explain the technique but leave it to you on how to evaluate it. So the integral we are required to evaluate is,
$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}\, \mathrm dx$$
Using the series expansion of cosine
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{2k-2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}\,\mathrm dx$$
Put $x=au \implies \mathrm dx=a\,\mathrm du$
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^{k}a^{2k-2}}{(2k)!}\int_{1}^{\frac{b}{a}}\frac{u^{2k-2}}{\sqrt{u^{2}-1}}\,\mathrm du $$
Now do a simple substitution,
Let $u=\cosh(\theta) \implies \mathrm du=\sinh(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$.

Then the integral will simplify to,
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{a^{2k-2}(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}\int_{0}^{A}\cosh^{2k-2}(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta$$
Where $A$ denotes the $\operatorname{arcosh}(\frac{b}{a})$.
Write $\cosh(\theta)=\frac{e^{\theta}+e^{-\theta}}{2}$ and use the binomial theorem ( break the sum at $0$ and continue from 1, because at 0 binomial theorem will not work.) So after we will be left with only summation term and integral will be solved. Summation will look like,
$$\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{a^{2k-2}(-1)^{k}}{(2k)!}\sum_{u=0}^{2k-2}\binom{2k-2}{u}2^{2-2k}\left(\frac{e^{A(2u-2k+2)}-1}{2u-2k+2}\right)$$
(I have ignored the value at $k=0$, because the important and dominating term will be mentioned summation)

Comment: Didn't you say in your comment that it will suffice to evaluate $I(t)$?

Comment: Exactly that's what I did right? But I let $t=1$, doing exactly what I have done one can also get $I(t)$ generalized.

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, Yaa, but again doing in the same way that I did, can also give a formula for $I(t)$. Actually I left it out for the reader. Also I didn't evaluate the exact answer. It's too complicated and I believe can be expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, I don't see why the generalization is difficult. See, $I(t)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(-t)^{k}}{(2k)!}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^{2k}}{\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}}$. Now the integral inside the summation already I explained how to evaluate right?

Comment: Yep. I wonder how the end sum can be evaluated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386662/reduction-formula-for-int-coshn-x-dx. Firstly use this reduction formula and we should see what summation looks like. And then we should see how to evaluate it. But it seems not soo easy. Summation term becomes too complicated

Comment: Thanks. I think leaving the summation as it is would be nicer for now. The summation seems to be pretty complicated for sure.

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari... Nooo wait. I just realised something now. Summation isn't too complicated at all. See my answer that I am about to edit

Comment: @RAHUL Aren't you missing a $\frac{1}{x^2}$ right after your first step?

Comment: @Gary I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Gary, someone was kind enough to edit my answer.

Comment: @Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, thank you for the edit. But I think it should be solved right from reduction process only, because the substitution you mentioned leaves us with where we started.

Comment: Thanks to everyone!!! It never occurred to me expand cos(x) as a series